# How does perovskite solar cell work?

Tags: semiconductor-physics, solar-cells

Do you dope the perovskite material the same way you dope silicon? Is there a P-type perovskite and N-type perovskite inside the cell?

Comment: It will take me some time to write an answer, but I also may point out that **several** perovskite questions were asked in this proposal which is still alive and active: https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/122958/materials-modeling?referrer=ZTUyZWY5OTQ1NDI4ZGVlMmU5MzM0ZThiZjNhOTRkYWFlMTA1NjM0OWEzOTZhYzlmMTBlNWQ4ZmIzYWE3MWFkN-4At28O9gekwyERVbYPhFIPwyHiajfB5BeMyrZKJaYV0 . You may consider joining that effort if you have questions of this sort.

Comment: Wikipedia seems to cover it broadly. The n and p regions are usually external to the perovskites.